# Linearization of the Derivative Block (MATLAB)

Tags: derivatives, matlab, linearization

In MATLABs documentation for the derivative block  [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/derivative.html), it states the following:

> The exact linearization of the Derivative block is difficult because the dynamic equation for the block is y=$\dot{u}$, which you cannot represent as a state-space system. However, you can approximate the linearization by adding a pole to the Derivative block to create a transfer function s/(c∗s+1).

Can anyone explain what it means to linearize the Derivative block? I thought differentiation was a linear operator, so I don't see why you'd want to linearize it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may look at [Improved Linearization with Transfer Fcn Blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/improved-linarization-transfer-fcn-blocks.html).

Comment: @Royi, thank you for the link. That helps a little but it still doesn't get at the heart of my question. It doesn't explain how the block is used to "approximate the linear behavior" and what that means.

Any chance you know why it doesn't have a state space representation?